How do I set generic 1x3 inputs and outputs in a Simulink model for code generation in C?
I recently started working with Matlab and Simulink. Now I was working on something that requires code generation of a Kalman filter. My problem is that I can't figure out how to set the filter inputs and outputs. They should all be, except the clock, 1x3 arrays, both inputs and outputs.
I don't understand how to make it so that I can generically set these values ​​on Simulink and then once the C code has been generated I can easily understand where the inputs and outputs are and modify them or use them in my code.
I tried using constant blocks, but then once the C code was generated I couldn't understand anything, not even where to go to set the inputs or at least use the outputs. I think it should be done with the "inport" and the "outport" blocks, but I don't know how to make them become 1x3 arrays, since they are scalars by default.
Is there a way to more easily understand the code generated by Simulink? Maybe I didn't understand where to look for what I need.enter image description here

If you are using Embedded Coder, then Model-to-Code Traceability will allow you to see how certain model elements trace to elements in the generated code.
There are a few ways to influence how Simulink / Embedded Coder generates code for parameters. I'd start by reading through this page, which gives a bit of an overview.
